# NodeJS defineClass - nested classes

Tags: oop, node.js

First of all, I'm quite new to both OOP and NodeJS.
My only experience with classes so far, are in PHP.

I'm trying to make a javascript class called Clients, using the defineClass module in NPM.
Then I want to add sub-classes to it, with even more functionality.
The reason I want some of the functionality in sub-classes, is because some of them might have quite alot of functionality.

Here is my code:

```
var defineClass = require("defineClass").defineClass

var Client = defineClass({
  scpConnected: false,

  constructor: function (socketId) {
    this.id = socketId;
  },

  test: function (test){
    console.log('Test!!! '+ test); 
  }
});

var SSH = defineClass({
  _super: Client,
  connected: false,
  busy: false,
  buffer: '',

  constructor: function () {
    queue = [];
  },

  ssh: {
    connect: function (IP) {
      console.log('Connecting to '+ IP +'...');
    }
  }
});

var client = new Client('Test');
client.ssh.connect();
```

It seems like "client" doesn't get the SSH abilities as I was expecting.

What am I doing wrong here? :)

**New Code**

```
var defineClass = require("defineClass").defineClass

var Client = defineClass({
  scpConnected: false,

  constructor: function (socketId) {
    this.id = socketId;
  },

  test: function (test){
    console.log('Test!!! '+ test); 
  },

  SSH: defineClass({  
      connected: false,
      busy: false,
      buffer: '',

      constructor: function () {
        queue = [];
      },

      connect: function (IP) {
        console.log('Connecting to '+ IP +'...');
      }
    })
});

var client = new Client('Test');
client.SSH.connect('test');
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be "var client = new SSH('Test');" Thats where you defined the ssh function. "SSH" is the child of "Client".

Comment: I tried that. The thing about it, that annoys me, is that you can't add more subclasses/functionality without changing the "var client" line. Maybe I misunderstood the way defineClass works. I want to "extend" like in the PHP example below.

Comment: So it works when you fix the code and now you are annoyed :D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in your sample, you are actually creating instance of Client instead of SSH:

```
 var client = new Client('Test');
 client.ssh.connect();
```

You should write:

```
 var client = new SSH('Test');
 client.ssh.connect();
```

Note that parent class doesn't have the functionality of its children, it's against the idea of inheritance.

Comment: I have a hard time accepting the syntax in Coffeescript. It's quite confusing to me.

Comment: Please delete the coffeescript "advise" and you'll get the +1 ;)

Comment: @madflow Ok, I do understand your reasons not to like this advise  :)

Comment: @Leaom I don't know how `defineClass` works, but I doubt `new SSH('Test')` will pass the `'Test'` down to the `Client` initializer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think I misunderstood how it works.
How can I add functionality to the parent class, like in the new code added above?
I'm going to have more abilities (FTP, Telnet, SCP) with their own set of commands.

Comment: @Drejer I can see two ways. First: `connect` should static method, but I can't find static methods in `defineClass` docs. Second, you should create instance of `client.SSH` via `var ssh = new client.SSH(); ssh.connect('test');`

Answer (score 0):

There are clearly some problems with inheritance.

Consider the following example (corresponding to your code) in PHP:

```
<?php

class Client {
    public function __construct($socketId) {
        $this->id = $socketId;
    }
}

class SSH extends Client {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->queue = new Array();
    }

    public $ssh = "whatever";
}

$client = new Client('Test');
//What is the $client->ssh now?

?>
```

Comment: My code is not PHP, but javascript running in NodeJS, which doesn't support classes in the same way. :)

Comment: Javascript does not support classes at all. It does not mean a library you use makes inheritance completely different from that of PHP (which, according to your words, you know better than JS). Did you read the code I provided?